# Compare two vars of T in a method of a generic class<T,U> (code port from C++ to C#)

Tags: c#, generics

How to compare two vars of type T in a method of a generic class< T, U >?
Here is an example code which throws the following compiler error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T'
>   and 'T'

```
class IntervalSet< T, U >
{
    public void Add ( T start, T end, ref U val )
    {
        // new interval is empty?
        if (start >= end) // ERROR
            return; 
    }
}
```

I try to port source from C++ to C# and C# is new to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Generics aren't templates. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this using generics - the best you can probably do is use `IComparable`.

Comment: Well how would you expect to compare them? What do you want to do if `T` is, say, a `Stream`? You could either constrain `T` to implement `IComparable<T>`, or you could pass in an `IComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must tell C# that `T` is comparable, otherwise you can only do `System.Object` things with `T` (and that's not much), excluding creating a new instance, since C# does not even know whether `T` has a default constructor:

```
class IntervalSet< T, U >
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public void Add ( T start, T end, ref U val )
    {
        if (start.CompareTo(end) >= 0) {
        }
    }
}
```

Note that standard types like `int`, `string`, `DateTime` etc. all implement this interface.

See: [IComparable<T> Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx),
        [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Just as a note to the OP, this is to support `CompareTo` through the `IComparable<T>` interface. Unfortunately, there is no way to say "require `T` to have a >= operator" in C#.

Comment: Now I've definded a interface base class for T where I define all the needed methodes. And then I write the generic like this: `class CIntervalSet<T> where T : TBase`